# C++11 rvalue references and variable initialisations

Tags: c++, string, c++11, reference, rvalue

Let's consider the following piece of code:

```
std::string&& rvalue_reference_1 = std::string("some string");
std::string   regular_string("some string");

std::string&& rvalue_reference_2 = "some string";
```

1. Are the first and the second statements behaving the same way ? I understand the first one as constructing a temporary object, and then simply "assigning a name" to it. Thus it becomes a regular object. Am I wrong somewhere ?
2. In the third statement, I'm not sure to understand what happens under the hood. "some string" is an anonymous/temporary `const char*`, and rvalue_reference_2 a rvalue reference to a `std::string` object, not a rvalue reference to a `const char*`... By writing `std::string&&`, do we implicitly call `std::string`'s constructor?

Comment: You answered the question by yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure whether non-const rvalue references extend a temporary object's lifetime… if they don't, then both lines 1. and 3. are Bad Things™.

Comment: @Matt For the first question, I was unsure of my own answer, but fine. Yet for my second one, I'm still a little bit confused...

Comment: @Croissant Indeed, I wouldn't write such "Bad Things™" in my code. I was just wondering if I... sort of... understand rvalue's functioning to some extent.

Comment: C++ always tries to automatically cast types if possible. In your case, it finds a `std::string&&` on the left hand side and a `const char *` at the right hand side. Thus the compiler looks for a constructor of `string` that takes a `const char *` argument. As there is such a constructor available, it call the constructor. Furthermore, constructing a `string` this way automatically gives an rvalue, thus, it can be assigned to the rvalue-reference on the left hand side.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The [wiki](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) \[[additional link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)\] says you can bind to an rvalue reference in c++11

Comment: @jaggedSpire Thanks, that's useful.